# Magento 2 - Change top navigation submenu position

Tags: magento2, php, layout, category, magento2.2

I create a new theme for Magento 2 based on Luma theme. I change the submenu of the top navigation to be 100% width.

```
.navigation .level0 .submenu {
    max-width: 1280px; 
    width: 1280px; 
    padding: 25px 0;
}
```

And now I want to change the submenu position, right now the submenu start right selected category, I need to made the submenu to start from left side.

I try to add `position: absolute;` and `left: 0;` but is not working.

How I can move this submenu to start from left side?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.ui-menu-item` - change position to `position: static;`

`.navigation > .ui-menu` - change position to `position: relative;`

```
.ui-menu-item {position: static;}
.navigation > .ui-menu {position: relative;}
```

It should do the trick ;)

UPDATE:
To override it through css use this:

```
.navigation ul {position: relative;}
.navigation li.level0 {position: static;}
.navigation .level0 .submenu {left: 0 !important;}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you but is not work. I have the feeling that the size position is calculated automatically with javascript, because when I select the submenu element I see this: element.style {display: block;left: -0.0333333px;top: 47.7333px;}

Comment: I think it doesn't  matter. The `left` value is almost zero. Element which is `absolute` is displayed based on position of nearest `relative` parent node. By default the `li` is relative, you need to change that to `static` and make `ul` relative.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a link. I've checked that. You got two options:

1. Locate javascript which calculates left position of submenu.
2. Force position through css. (see edited answer)

Comment: I have one request to you please remove that image, it contain logo and a lot of things. thanks

Comment: and is not work because the left position is calculated in front of the css so our left: 0 will be disabled

Comment: Sure I deleted the image. 
That's why I added `!important` which should overload inline css.

Comment: sorry I don't understand very well how I can overload inline css?

Comment: `.navigation .level0 .submenu {left: 0 !important;}` That's it. The `!important` rule should do that.